# How to get the count and total sum of a MultiIndex Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

`df_n_pr_stores_qty.groupby(['Store_type','prod_cat']).count()`

```
                             QTY
Store_type      prod_cat    

Flagship        Bags        2726
                Books       14766
                Clothing    5844
                Electronics 9950
MBR             Bags        2936
                Books       14868
                Clothing    6198
                Footwear    6105
TeleShop        Bags        2854
                Books       13836
```

- How to get the which store has count of `prod_cat` of each store in descending order
- What is the Total Qty of each order

Expected Out `q1`

```
Flagship        4
MBR             4
TeleShop        2
```

`q2`

```
Flagship    33,296‬
MBR         ‭30,107‬
TeleShop    ‭16,690‬
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do:

```
# df is your multiindex df
>>> df.groupby(level=0).count()

            values
Store_type        
Flagship         4
MBR              4
TeleShop         2

>>> df.groupby(level=0).sum()

            values
Store_type        
Flagship     33286
MBR          30107
TeleShop     16690
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(index_col=0, sep='\s\s+')
```

1:

```
df.groupby(level=0).count()
```

2:

```
df.groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Or, if you have many columns:

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg({"QTY": "sum"})
```